# Unable to open rosbag files in C++

Tags: rosbag, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to write a node to edit the timestamps in a bag file, using C++. The code I have written is attached below. I have tried to follow the template given in the rosbag C++ API, but I am unable to open any of the bag files I have, even though they run perfectly well when I play them back using rosbag play. Specifically, I am seeing the error message

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rosbag::BagIOException'
  what():  Error opening file: ~/catkin_ws/src/publish_text/launch/filtered.bag
```

I am not quite sure why exactly this is happening. Would greatly appreciate it if anyone had any suggestions!

Thanks. (Code from the main function of my code enclosed below)

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "postprocessing");

ros::NodeHandle nh("~");

std::string instr, outstr;

rosbag::Bag inbag, outbag;

if (nh.getParam("input_path", instr)) {
  inbag.open(instr, rosbag::bagmode::Read);
} else {
  ROS_ERROR("No input path provided, terminating\n");
  exit(1);
}

if (!nh.getParam("output_path", outstr)) {
  outbag.open(outstr, rosbag::bagmode::Write);
} else {
  ROS_ERROR("No output path provided, terminating\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

---

UPDATE: I was able to resolve the issue by replacing the path with an absolute path from the root directory.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222046/unable-to-open-rosbag-files-in-c++/) by [jll](https://answers.ros.org/users/22928/jll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-12-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-08-02**:
Does `rosbag::Bag` API support relative paths like this: `rosbag::Bag::open("./name_of_bagfile")` ? I'm using ROS Groovy default install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rosbag::BagIOException'
> ```

```
  what():  Error opening file: ~/catkin_ws/src/publish_text/launch/filtered.bag
```

Most likely you are expecting the C++ runtime to resolve/replace the `~` with the path to the users home directory. Afaik that behaviour is implemented by the shell (ie: `bash`), it's not something that works everywhere.

Can you try to provide an absolute (or even relative) path to `rosbag::Bag::open(..)`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-08-02**:
I have the same problem when adding a relative path (absolute path works fine) as such: `rosbag::Bag::open("./name_of_bagfile.bag")`

**Comment by [antoineniotna](https://answers.ros.org/users/34023/antoineniotna/) on 2019-05-06**:
Did you managed to use the relative path ? I have exactly the same problem, absolute path is working fine but the relative one doesn't. I am using kinetic version.